# how to make a bootstrap container disappear in specific page in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to rails and I want my container to be displayed in all pages except about page, I already have created about controller also about page design, and this is my application.html.erb code :

```
<header>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <% if params[:controller] == 'games' && params[:action] == 'index' %>
            <h1>The GameStore </h1>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <section>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8">

    <%= yield %>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <%= render 'partials/sidebar' %>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap container inside this

```
<% unless current_page?(about_path) # or whatever is your about route path helper %>  
  <div class = 'container'>
    ...
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: if I type the code you give, it shows blank in my about page. Where should I put the code you gave.

Comment: Actually I created a controller named about, then I designed the about page in the index page, but above the <% yield %> code, I put all the containers and the columns, so all my pages are being controlled by this code. When I type your code, my main index page and the sidebar disappeared

Answer (score 0):

```
    <% unless current_page?(about_path) # or whatever is your about route path helper %>  
      <div class = 'container'>
        ...
      </div>

<%else%>
```

...the code for the about_path

```
 <% end %>
```

You can also work with layouts. May be that suites you more. 
In your about_controller put this at the beginning.

```
layout 'about'
```

and than create a layout that is called **layouts/layout.html.erb** 
you can also render a layout in a specific action from you controller. So at the end of

*about_controller.rb*

```
def index
your code
render :layout => 'about'
end
```

the layouts/about.html.erb file you can design like your application.html.erb but take out whatever you do not need..

Comment: Actually I created a controller named about, then I designed the about page in the index page, but above the <% yield %> code, I put all the containers and the columns, so all my pages are being controlled by this code. When I type your code, my main index page and the sidebar disappeared